# Visa refusal for the UK, what can I do?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

The decision:

> you have submitted an invitation from the British army which state you
>   have been invitated you for an interview and assessment. I note that
>   the letter provided does not guarantee your enlistment. You have
>   provided no explaination for your apparent new interest in joining the
>   British army and you have nothing to indicate that you have ever
>   sought to join the military of your home

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOvZb.jpg]

My question is that could there be that maybe someone removed my visa application letter? Because to my understanding it's like I only provided the invitation letter? And the bank balance from my business account show I have enough money that there is no resonable reason for me to go and do the assessment which am not sure of being enlisted. The the bank balance is 8000pounds and my budget was to use 4500 because I don't know what's out therefore I needed to be financial stable yet they have used it as I have money and I cant go to UK for just an assessment and spend that amount forgetting there is air ticket, hotel bookings, logistics plus pocket money.

And there decision I can not apeal why?

Comment: Visas for British Army assessments are notoriously difficult to obtain, as the main requirement for a visa (applicant has strong ties to home country and will return there after the visa term) are in direct conflict with the requirements for a good enlistee (applicant can leave the home country and not return). Search for "UK army assessment" using the search box (at the top of this page where it says "Search on Travel...") and you'll find lots of information about this difficult subject.

Comment: I see, so what should I do? I can not miss this assessment can I appeal ?

Comment: You should search as I suggested, and read the questions and answers that returned.

Comment: @cidrickzimbiri in the UK, a business bank account is for business expenditure and its unlawful to use those funds for personal use - you need to show that this is legal in your country, that you have the legal right to use your business funds to support your trip to the UK for purposes unrelated to your business.

Comment: @moo to prove this where do I get this proof, is it the bank ? Becouse here in Malawi a sole owner business it's u who makes the decisions it's your money...or should I put this money in a personal account and indicate the source as it is from the business. Confused

Comment: @cidrickzimbiri typically you pay yourself a wage from the business, or there is an indication after taxation as to what is "disbursable", ie what can be used for personal use.  You should be able to prove this with tax documents or the like.  The bank doesn't care, it won't (and shouldnt) give you permission because its not there to determine what is legally yours and what is legally the businesses.  If you put the money into your personal account, you still need to prove where it came from and that you can legally use it (ie payslips), otherwise you will fail under funds parking rules.

Comment: @cidrickzimbiri your other issue is that the immigration official simply does not believe that you intend to spend half your available funds, and a third of your annual income, on something which basically amounts to a 19 day holiday with absolutely zero guarantee of enlistment in the British armed forces - and he would be right.  Its an absurd amount of money to spend on such a venture in my opinion.  That is going to be harder to overcome than the issue of your source of funds.

Comment: @Moo you seem to be confusing *business* and *corporation.*  Perhaps UK law does not allow sole proprietorship, but it's certainly allowed, for example, in the US.  It is the default organization of a business, in fact: if you set up a stand in front of your house to sell lemonade, without forming a corporation or partnership, you are a sole proprietor.

Comment: @moo I get you..so should I apply again? And correct this mistakes and stand a chance of getting a Visa? All an appeal help since it's there where it has to be mentioned that in our country it's legaly to use business account for other purposes

Comment: @phoog I’m not confusing anything, I’m saying the OP has to prove that they can use the funds, and that requires more than proof of ownership of any business - tax and other things need to be taken into account for example.  We have a whole range of “businesses” in the UK, but without evidence to show what type of business it is, you can’t fault the immigration official for erring on the side of caution - other answers here have shown that UK immigration watch out for things like tax fraud etc in applications for instance.

Comment: No way I dd add the tax clearence certificate...I don't know what to do

Comment: @cidrick zimbiri You can’t appeal because UK Immigration Rules do not allow appeals on visitor visa decisions. As to your finances, you should separate your business and personal funds by opening a separate business bank account and provide accountant-certified trading/P&L accounts so that the ECO can understand what money is yours and what belongs to the business (eg to pay creditors) and if the business is profitable. There’s no point reapplying until you can provide at least 6 months’ statements on this basis. You’ll just be refused again. Read the duplicate question, it explains everything

Comment: As a general rule it's a bad idea to use a visa agent. Most do not care about anything but taking your money, and if someone is refused a visa, it means they can try to get even more money out of that person when they reapply. They have no incentive to prepare a successful application, and much incentive to prepare -- intentionally -- an unsuccessful one! It is almost always best to prepare your visa application yourself.

Comment: @traveller thanks alot I hv jst changed my assessment day to next year so that I should get well prepared all the mistakes have been noted.

Comment: @michael I have also noted that Visa somes times it's jst luck..the way I applied someone was given a Visa while I was refused.